# Calculate the display width of a string - difference between Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, string

i have to calculate the length in pixel of a string both in java and C#. I use respectively these piece of code

**Java**

```
 Font font = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14);
 Canvas component = new Canvas();
 System.out.println(component.getFontMetrics(font).stringWidth("0"));
```

**C#**

```
float fontWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("0", new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 14, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)).Width;
Console.WriteLine(fontWidth);
```

The problem is that the results obtained are completely different from Java and C#. For example

- "*Calibri*" 11:   Java = 6px C# = 15px
- "*Calibri*" 14: Java = 7px C# = 20px
- "*Arial*" 14: Java = 8px C# = 21px

Any idea why? Is there any heuristic to apply to get similar result?

thanks

Comment: You use two different fonts ;-)

Comment: Is it correct that you use two different fonts to compare both results?

Comment: Sorry. I corrected. As i wrote in the post for Calibri 14 the java code return 7 while the C# code return 20.

Comment: Maybe the base to calculate the pixels width are different.

Comment: what do you mean with "the base to calculate"?

Comment: Have look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography). In section "History" is an example about different views width of letter 'M'. Different persons have different views those cast these into programming code (That's a theory of mine).

Comment: You haven't supplied a device context to MeasureWidth

Comment: "The default behaviour of MeasureText is to add padding for overhanging glyphs". You may need to turn this off by specifying relevant flags : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How can i get the deviceContext? i haven't any event, (for example PaintEventArgs).